# Magento catalog price rule condition 'contains' not working

Tags: magento, conditional-statements, catalog, magento-rules

I am using Magento and am trying to create a promotion using catalog price rules. I want to use the SKU as a condition. If I do the following:

**SKU equals N12380_Black**

it works fine.

However if I do:

**SKU contains N12380**

it doesn't work at all. I need it to work so that I can apply the rule to multiple items in one go. The Magento version is 1.5.0.1

Is there a bug in this version that could be causing a problem? If so does anybody know a fix for it? I simply cannot see what I've done wrong - I've checked all the SKU details, but nothing seems to work.

It appears as though the rule script is in **app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Condition/Abstract.php** if that helps anyone.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Just so you know this is actually a bug, you can find more info here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/97299/2380

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using the conditional 'is one of' and listing all the SKU's - using contains isn't the way to do what I was trying.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested on Magento 1.5.0.1 yet, but on both 1.4.1.1 and 1.5.1.0 this catalog rule works fine.
Maybe you have some extension that extends rule functionality? Most of them rewrite standard functions and that may cause errors.